# TS2786 TypeScript not reconizing UI-Kitten components

Tags: typescript, react-native, typescript-eslint, react-native-ui-kitten

**Error message on IDE:**

> TS2786: 'ApplicationProvider' cannot be used as a JSX component.
> Its instance type 'ApplicationProvider' is not a valid JSX element. 
> The types returned by 'render()' are incompatible between these types.
>
> Type 'React.ReactNode' is not assignable to type 'import("C:/Users/someuser/node_modules/@types/react/index").ReactNode'.
> Type '{}' is not assignable to type 'ReactNode'.
> Type '{}' is not assignable to type 'ReactPortal'.

Not just ApplicationProvider, but every component that I imported from UI-kitten/components has the "not a valid JSX element" error.

```
/**
 * Sample React Native App
 * https://github.com/facebook/react-native
 *
 * Generated with the UI Kitten TypeScript template
 * https://github.com/akveo/react-native-ui-kitten
 *
 * Documentation: https://akveo.github.io/react-native-ui-kitten/docs
 *
 * @format
 */

import React from 'react';
import {
  ImageProps,
  StyleSheet,
} from 'react-native';
import {
  ApplicationProvider,
  Button,
  Icon,
  IconRegistry,
  Layout,
  Text,
} from '@ui-kitten/components';
import { EvaIconsPack } from '@ui-kitten/eva-icons';
import * as eva from '@eva-design/eva';

/**
 * Use any valid `name` property from eva icons (e.g `github`, or `heart-outline`)
 * https://akveo.github.io/eva-icons
 */
const HeartIcon = (props?: Partial<ImageProps>): React.ReactElement<ImageProps> => (
  <Icon {...props} name='heart'/>
);

export default (): React.ReactFragment => (
  <>
    <IconRegistry icons={EvaIconsPack}/>
    <ApplicationProvider {...eva} theme={eva.light}>
      <Layout style={styles.container}>
        <Text style={styles.text} category='h1'>
          Welcome to UI Kitten 
        </Text>
        <Text style={styles.text} category='s1'>
          Start with editing App.js to configure your App
        </Text>
        <Text style={styles.text} appearance='hint'>
          For example, try changing theme to Dark by using eva.dark
        </Text>
        <Button style={styles.likeButton} accessoryLeft={HeartIcon}>
          LIKE
        </Button>
      </Layout>
    </ApplicationProvider>
  </>
);

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  text: {
    textAlign: 'center',
  },
  likeButton: {
    marginVertical: 16,
  },
});
```

**Reproduce:**

```
npx react-native init MyApp --template @ui-kitten/template-ts
```

It seems like when updating the @types/react to the latest version (18.0.6) will solve the problem. But then EXPO is not supporting version 18. It also seems like a problem only raised recently.

Comment: did you created a ts or tsx file?

Comment: everything comes natively from the official template @ui-kitten/template-ts

Comment: I'm also facing the same issue. Have you been able to resolve the issue?

Comment: I'm also facing the same and following this post for a solution

Answer (score 2):

Solution [here](https://github.com/akveo/react-native-ui-kitten/issues/1595).

1. Add `"resolutions": { "@types/react": "~17.0.21" },` to `package.json`
2. Delete `node_modules`
3. Reinstall with `yarn install` or equivalent